# m2e extension is not installing in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e

When I am installing the m2e extension, it is giving me below error:

I am using this url to download:   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.6.1.20150625-2338)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.0.20150526-2032 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.6.0.20150526-2032) requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.6.1.20150625-2338) requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e Marketplace 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.discovery 1.6.1.20150625-2338)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.6.0,1.7.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.6.1.20150625-2338)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.discovery [1.6.1.20150625-2338]
```

Comment: Did you bother to read the error output? `requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found`  Do you have this library available in your Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use below link:
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4

You might be using older version of eclipse and trying to install latest version of maven.

Comment: m2e 1.4.x are not compatible with the Luna releases. If you look at the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" package list, it includes m2e 1.5.1 and Orbit Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java 15.0. Also, if you actually install m2e 1.4.1 into Luna release, there is a ClassDefNotFoundException for a class called BasicLocation that occurs during repository indexing. Please see my answer to this question for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me when installing m2e 1.6.2 into Eclipse 4.2.2 (Luna SR2) was add the Orbit project *Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java* 15.0 bundle from the Orbit project into Eclipse **before** installing m2e.

(The install error I initially got said m2e 1.6.2 is looking for the Guava 14 bundle, which I could not locate in any of the recommended Orbit builds, but Guava 15 seems to be working just fine so far, and indeed the Guava 15 bundle is what the [Luna SR2 Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/lunasr2) uses.)

I used this URL for the Orbit build repository for Luna SR2: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20150124073747/repository/

This specific link could be unstable over time, or maybe you are reading this because of issues with different versions of Eclipse or m2e, so in those cases it would be a good idea to check the [Orbit downloads](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/) page to find the right Orbit build for to match your Eclipse release.

For those who are not old Eclipse hands, here is step by step what I did to install the Orbit Guava bundle into Eclipse 4.4.2:

From the Eclipse menu: Help > Install New Software...

- Click on the **Add** button. In the resulting dialog, enter:

  - Name: Orbit Repository for Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2)
  - Location: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20150124073747/repository/
- Click **OK**

Once this repository is added to your Eclipse configuration, the m2e feature installation process will be able to find and install the Guava bundle automatically.

The m2e installation may also want to update other packages, so it is a good idea to have the Eclipse Luna update site available prior to the m2e feature install:

- Click the Add button again. In the resulting dialog, enter:

  - Name: Eclipse Update Site
  - Location: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4
- Click OK

It's also worth noting that the m2e 1.6.x release line is included in Mars, while the 1.5.x is included in Luna, so that it might be a more conservative choice to use a 1.5 release rather than a 1.6 release.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a quick answer : Ignore the error.

Actually I'm not quite sure this is the right solution but at least for me it worked just fine. I'm sharing my case because it might help someone.

While I was installing m2e extension, I met the same error message you met. But I ignored the error and was able to continue installing. And then the installation have finished successfully.

Click and take a look at the image 
: [Install Remadiation Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie8qO.png)

I saw the error when I clicked "show original error ... ". But I think it's OK to choose "Keep my installation ... " and click "Next" to continue

Comment: it's not a solution. Installing eclipse plugins error has different reasons. Right here - `incubating components`. Conflict appears in using time later.